# How to recognize the audio stream format?

Tags: java, android, mp3, aac

Here I have the code which records a audio stream to file. The problem is I'd like to save this file with correct file extension (mainly .mp3 and .aac). How can I achieve this?

```
URLConnection conn = new URL(StringUrls[0]).openConnection();
            InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();

            BufferedOutputStream bufOutstream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(env.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/temp.file")));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int len = in.read(buffer);
            while (len != -1) {
                bufOutstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                len = in.read(buffer);

                if (Recorder.this.isCancelled) break;

            }
            bufOutstream.close();
```

Comment: You need to analyze stream content - look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360286/detect-if-file-is-mp3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to take a look at the binary data while you already have it in your hands. According to this [File signatures table](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) both MP3 and AAC have unique magic headers:

- `49 44 33` for *MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3 (MP3) audio file*
- `FF F1` for *MPEG-4 Advanced Audio Coding (AAC) Low Complexity (LC) audio*
- `FF F9` for *MPEG-2 Advanced Audio Coding (AAC) Low Complexity (LC) audio*