# Encryption/Decryption best algorithm for files on android devices

Tags: android, facebook, algorithm, encryption, facebook-conceal

I am developing an app which require it to save .mp3 files(extension already changed) on sdcard.
I want to encrypt those files so that it cannot be played directly just by changing extension.
I have used AES/ECB and conceal from facebook .From several attempts it can be inferred that conceal is much efficient than AES/ECB. 
Is there any other algorithm which is efficient than these algorithms to encrypt/decrypt files not more than 15 mb.

Any help ll be highly appreciated.

Comment: Shift two bits right and while playing shift two bits left. No one else will be able to play it unless they know what you did.

Comment: @Rohit5k2, Already tried ,vlc is able to play these shifted bits file.

Comment: VLC probably figures out what you did because it recognises the file header, even in a bit-shifted version. If you replace the mp3-header with your own header format, and at playback recreate an mp3-header from it, you may not have to encrypt the data itself.

Comment: @m69 ,It ll be helpful if you provide any link or code snippet.

Comment: Apparently there's no overall mp3 file header, just chunk headers. If you change the identification parts of these, the file should become unreadable to audio players. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360286/detect-if-file-is-mp3, http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html

Comment: @m69, Yeah... you are right . Encrypting chunk headers ll not do any visible good from the user point of view.